# Setting parameters in a block

Tags: ruby

I have seen a style of setting method parameters in a block (for example in Faraday) like this:

```
conn.post do |req|
  req.url '/nigiri'
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = '{ "name": "Unagi" }'
end
```

1. What is this called?
2. How does it work under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a 'higher order function'. `conn.post` is a method that calls another method (which you define in the block)

This is a simple example:

```
def call_block; yield; end
puts call_block { true }
# => true
```

you can pass arguments to `yield` as well:

```
def yield_args(*args)
  yield args
end
yield_args(1, 2) { |item| item }
# => [1,2]
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Could also be worth mentioning that the reason you would do this in a situation like the OP mentioned is that `conn.post` could do the initial work of creating the `req` object, provide that to the block to allow further customization of the object, and then possibly take further action with `req` after the customization has taken place.

Comment: I think this whole "you can turn a block into a proc like this" is irrelevant here.